# wildfly log4j2 ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log

Tags: wildfly, log4j2

trying to configure wildfly to use log4j2.  Following the instructions here:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-log/how-to-use-log4j2-in-your-wildfly-applications/

Whenever org.apache.commons.logging is excluded:

```
 <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>         
</exclusions>
```

or the logging subsystem is excluded as in:

```
<exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="logging"/>
</exclude-subsystems>
```

I end up with:

undertow-deployment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log

If I don't exclude the org.apache.commons.logging and/or the logging subsystem, I get no errors, but the system is not reading my log4j2.xml file either.

Comment: When excluding the module, are you also include a commons-logging library in your deployment?

Comment: no the only commons library i have in my deployment is: commons-cli-1.5.0.jar  commons-collections4-4.1.jar  commons-io-2.1.jar  commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar

Comment: If you’re excluding it from your deployment, then you need to add it in your deployment it looks like. There is something in your deployment requiring it.

Comment: ok I see what you are saying, so I did some more digging.  I'm using quartz scheduler the version I am using has a dependency on commons logging.  I also figured out I'm using jboss serialization - which has a log4j v1 dependency.  Any suggestions on how to deal with libraries needing log4j1 and commons logging in this situation?

Comment: Works!  I added commons-logging and log4j1 jars into my deployment and excluded the 3 modules for deployment and all sub-deployments.  The system is now reading my log4j2.xml file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to James Perkins for helping me figure this out.  I had libraries that were referencing commons-logging and also log4j1.  The solution is to include log4j1 and commons-logging jars in the deployment while at the same time, excluding the 3 modules above in jboss-deployment-structure.xml.